# Is there a way to delete "node_modules" except for one package (mocha)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack, mocha.js

I want to remove the `node_modules` folder after I deploy my app on Heroku and at the same time I want my unit tests to work.

I tried adding the deletion of the `node_modules` on the `heroku-postbuild` script in `package.json`. It worked correct but then my `"test"` script fails because they don't find the `mocha` module.

As far as I know those scripts run in parallel, so putting the deletion of the `node_modules` in the `"test"` script won't work either. Do you have any workaround for this problem?

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && del-cli ./node_modules/* ",
"test": "mocha -r source-map-support/register ./dist/tests.js"
```

Further info:

I want to delete it because its size. I have a Heroku warning after every deploy that says that the slug size has exceeded. The folder is taking more than 200MB. And I don't need the `node_modules` after I deploy because my app is bundled using Webpack. My only problem is when running my unit tests, the only package I need from `node_modules` is `mocha`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why are you trying to delete `node_modules/` after building? Normally you should let Heroku build your dependencies and then leave `node_modules/` alone. After all, you probably need the libraries it contains at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to delete it because its size. I have a warning after every deploy that says that the slug size has exceeded. The folder is taking more than 200MB. And I don't need the 'node_modules' after I deploy because my app is bundled using webpack. My only problem is when running my unit test, I mean the only package I need from node_modules is mocha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to delete it because its size. I have a Heroku warning after every deploy that says that the slug size has exceeded. The folder is taking more than 200MB. And I don't need the `node_modules` after I deploy because my app is bundled using Webpack. My only problem is when running my unit tests, the only package I need from `node_modules/` is `mocha`.

In this case, most of your dependencies aren't actually `dependencies`, but `devDependencies`.

If you keep `mocha` in your `dependencies` and move everything else to `devDependencies` you shouldn't have to do anything special. Heroku [prunes `devDependencies` by default after building your slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation).